# Any harm in using str_replace on htmlentities?

Tags: php, html-entities

I have a custom forum in which I employ htmlentities so users aren't able to post malicious code(html/js).  Anyway, as I am pulling posts from the database, I use str_replace in order to show certain html elements <, >, &, etc.. is there any harm in doing this?  Will it cause side effects/html to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. User posts data
2. Data is escaped for mysql, written to DB
3. User makes request for data
4. Data is encoded for display (aggressively with `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`, or some subset of allowed characters.  You could do this with `str_replace`, but there are better utilities).

Answer (score 0):

Use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to avoid any html / js / php.
It has some options to allow any tags you want like this:

```
strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags`, as stated in the documentation will not remove inline javascript or sanitise so it isn't a good idea. A common solution is to use `bbcode` instead for which many libraries exist, or you can make your own and then use `preg_replace` to substitute in your own markup safely.

**Here's a quick sample:**

```
$safe_output = htmlspecialchars($output);
$find = array("'\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]'is");
$replace = array("<strong>\\1</strong>");
$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, nl2br($safe_output));
```

Comment: substitute in your own markup safely, in your own markup safely, your own markup safely, own markup safely, markup safely, **safely**... safely, you say?

Comment: @webarto Do you always make no sense, no sense, no sense at all?